# Printing to a new line after sorting a text file

Tags: python, sorting

For my task I have to be able to print the data that is in text file after it has been sorted. I have been able to sort it but it dosen't print it to a new line even though in notepad they are on seperate lines.

My Notepad Documents has this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn0pT.png

The code I already have set up is:

```
file = open(class_name , 'a')   #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
name = (name)
file.write(str(name + " : " )) #writes the information to the file
file.write(str(score))
file.write('\n')
file.close()    #safely closes the file to save the information

viewscore = input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class").lower()

if viewscore == "yes".lower():
   f = open(class_name , "r")
   lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
   f.close()
   lines.sort()
   print (lines)
```

The Variables I have are:

```
class_name = class_name + ".txt"  
name = input().title()
```

Then when run the output I get is:

```
['Dan : 0\n', 'Jana : 0\n', 'Kyle : 0\n']
```

Please tell me if I have to add anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add what you would like the output to be, please?  Also - can you explain what sorting you're trying to achieve?  `lines.sort()` will sort the list (`lines`) as strings, so you'll get the names in alphabetical order - is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for late response been busy. For it I have to be able to sort it in alphabetical and numerical form. If possible how would I get the user to input whether they want to sort it in numerical or alphabetical sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a work version for me:

```
class_name = 'data.txt'
name = 'Jim'
score = 100
file = open(class_name , 'a')   #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information

line_data = name + " : " + str(score) + "\n" # data to write
file.write(line_data)
file.close()    #safely closes the file to save the information

viewscore = raw_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class?").lower()

if viewscore == "yes".lower():
   f = open(class_name , "r")
   lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
   f.close()
   lines.sort()
   for line in lines:
      print line
else: # add else case to debug
   print 'no for', viewscore
```

First, you can put the line you want to write in a variable, and then write it.

Second, if you use Python2.x, use `raw_input()` for input string.

Third, if you have a `if`, better to write an `else` for easy to debug the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked. Just wondering would there be a way I would be able to group scores if the same name is inputted so it would be like Kyle: 0, 5, 10 etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code. Why are you writing 3 things separately? It is probably writing \n as a string, not putting things in new line.

```
f.write(name+' : '+str(score)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing is the list you called `lines` and the way you see the output is the way the type list is displayed. What you want to do is print the content of the list as one string. For that you can `join` the content as follow:

```
In [1]: lines = ['Dan : 0\n', 'Jana : 0\n', 'Kyle : 0\n']
In [2]: print "".join(lines)
Dan : 0
Jana : 0
Kyle : 0
```